# Replace word with special characters from string in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I am writing a method which should replace all words which matches with ones from the list with '****'

characters. So far I have code which works but all special characters are ignored.

I have tried with ***"\\W"*** in my expression but looks like I didn't use it well so I could use some help.

Here's code I have so far:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < badWords.size(); i++) {
        if (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(stringToCheck, badWords.get(i))) {
            stringToCheck = stringToCheck.replaceAll("(?i)\\b" + badWords.get(i) + "\\b", "****");
        }
    }
```

E.g. I have list of words ['bad', '@$$'].

If I have a string: `"This is bad string with @$$"` 
I am expecting this method to return `"This is **** string with ****"`

Note that method should be aware of case sensitive words, e.g. `TesT` and `test` should handle same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you use the `StringUtils` you can just directly replace words that match the bad words.  This code works for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> badWords = new ArrayList<String>();
    badWords.add("test");
    badWords.add("BadTest");
    badWords.add("\\$\\$");
    String test = "This is a TeSt and a $$ with Badtest.";
    for(int i = 0; i < badWords.size(); i++) {
            test = test.replaceAll("(?i)" + badWords.get(i), "****");
    }
    test = test.replaceAll("\\w*\\*{4}", "****");
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

Output:

```
This is a **** and a **** with ****.
```

Comment: You are right, IF is redundant here, thank you. But still, if you add word like @$$ in array, replaceAll will fail to replace it.

Comment: @jasenkoh Try my updated code it should work now. JonM is right you should escape special characters also you should change your regex.

Comment: It works, but it's case sensitive that's one more thing I need to care of.

Comment: @jasenkoh just add your `(?i)` back in I updated my post...it should work for case insensitive matches now.

Comment: I am really sorry to bother you @brso05 but there is one more thing that needs to be handled. if there is a word in array: `SuperTest` expected output should be `****` instead of `Super****`, that's why I had `\\b`. Please take a look [link](http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/201211). By adding `\\b` special characters are ignored

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that these special characters e.g.  `$` are regex control characters and not literal characters. You'll need to escape any occurrence of the following characters in the bad word using two backslashes:

`{}()\[].+*?^$|`

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your list of bad words contains special characters that have particular meanings when interpreted in a regular expression (which is what the `replaceAll` method does).  `$`, for example, typically matches the end of the string/line.  So I'd recommend a combination of things:

- Don't use `containsIgnoreCase` to identify whether a replacement needs to be done.  Just let the `replaceAll` run each time - if there is no match against the bad word list, nothing will be done to the string.
- The characters like `$` that have special meanings in regular expressions should be escaped when they are added into the bad word list.  For example, `badwords.add("@\\$\\$");`

Comment: This is great suggestion, but I am having hard time to combine to match exact words and words with special characters. I use `\\b` to match word but looks like it somehow ignores special characters than.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
    String stringToCheck = "This is b!d string with @$$";
    List<String> badWords = asList("b!d","@$$");
    for(int i = 0; i < badWords.size(); i++) {
        if (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(stringToCheck,badWords.get(i))) {
            stringToCheck = stringToCheck.replaceAll("["+badWords.get(i)+"]+","****");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(stringToCheck);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution: bad words matched with word boundaries (and case insensitive).

```
    Pattern badWords = Pattern.compile("\\b(a|b|ĉĉĉ|dddd)\\b",
            Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    String text = "adfsa a dfs bb addfdsaf ĉĉĉ adsfs dddd asdfaf a";
    Matcher m = badWords.matcher(text);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(text.length());
    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, stars(m.group(1)));
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    String cleanText = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(text);
    System.out.println(cleanText);
}

private static String stars(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("(?su).", "*");
    /*
    int cpLength = s.codePointCount(0, s.length());
    final String stars = "******************************";
    return cpLength >= stars.length() ? stars : stars.substring(0, cpLength);
    */
}
```

And then (in comment) the stars with the correct count: one star for a Unicode code point giving two surrogate pairs (two UTF-16 chars).